# Imputing categorical 'string' data for missing values in python

Tags: classification, random-forest, missing-data, data-imputation

I'm working on binary classifier model with 30% N/A values aka missing fields.

I have one continuous feature and two categorical 'string' features missing in my data.

For a continuous feature, I've imputed 'mean'.

Can someone guide me how could I Impute categorical 'string' data? Does Random forests/Decision tree will overcome this?